# Bought a slot-loading BD-RE drive, but it spits out every disc I feed it without spinning. What do?

Tags: windows-8.1, hardware-failure, optical-drive, blu-ray, disc

I bought an internal UJ-267 (slot-loading BD-RE) drive, and I put it into my laptop.

The trouble is that whenever I insert a disc into it (whether it's a CD or a DVD; I don't have a BD around to try it with), it fails to read the disc.

Specifically, it never even spins -- I just hear (what seems to be) a mechanical attempt to fit the disc around its spindle, but that just fails, and the disc gets spit back out. The drive seems to be recognized fine by the computer and all (I see "BD-RE Drive" in My Computer), but otherwise I have never heard the disc spinning.

Does this mean the drive is defective, or am I possibly doing something wrong?
Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot or otherwise use it (e.g. might it work externally?), or is returning it my only option? Are there any diagnostic tools I can use to check error codes or similar?

Comment: Check that the eject button isn't stuck. You could also try inserting the discs upside down although I very much doubt that the drive operates that way. I suspect it is probably faulty.

Comment: I tried upside down and it didn't make a difference; I can't find an eject button though. But when I try "eject" in My Computer it does attempt to eject reasonably, so it seems to be fine in that respect? I suspect it's faulty as well...

Comment: @James: Actually, could it be that it's attempting to draw more power than  my laptop will output? I'm not sure if a BD drive needs more power than a DVD drive (although I was inserting a DVD regardless).

Comment: I assume you cannot return the drive?, it is defective.

Comment: @Moab: Well I can, but it's a hassle and I want to use it if possible.

Comment: @Mehrdad, sounds like you already have more hassles trying to make a defective drive work.